# javascript challenge on CodeWars: what's wrong with my solution?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I'm fairly new to programming and javascript, and recently started working on CodeWars challenges. I wasn't able to pass the challange below with my solution, and even when I compared against solutions from other users, I couldn't find what the issue was with mine.

Challenge:

**"Complete the squareSum/square_sum/SquareSum method so that it squares each number passed into it and then sums the results together.**

**For example:
squareSum([1, 2, 2]); // should return 9"**

My code:

```
function squareSum(numbers){
  var sqNum = numbers.map(num=>num*num);
  var addNum = sqNum.reduce((acc,curr)=> acc + curr);
  return addNum
};
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: What is wrong with this code ? Any errors ?

Comment: I tested it and it works fine. What is your outcome?

Comment: There are multiple possible reasons to fail a challenge. Your code appears to be correct, but performing a full copy potentially fails the time requirements for the "large array" test cases. Try performing the square operation directly in the reduce.

Comment: looks ok, but you have superfluous colon at the end of the function block.

Comment: What if one of the array values is zero?

Answer (score 2):

```
function squareSum(numbers){
    return numbers.reduce((acc,curr)=> acc + curr * cur, 0);
}
```

Avoid the full copy with map. You will most likely hit either the run time or memory limit for the test cases with large arrays.

CodeWars is not only about correct implementation, but also about reasonable efficiency.

Comment: So just realized there was no test written for this challenge. So does the test result in an error by default, until actual test cases are written by the person completing the challenge?When I actually submitted my final answer it passed.

Answer (score 1):

This solution per se is working ok, I have tried at codepen. It has to be with the way you present your answer. I don't know how exactly codewars works, but keep in mind that you are not calling the function `squareSum` anywhere.
And when you do it, remember to pass the numbers within an array.

```
function squareSum(numbers){
  var sqNum = numbers.map(num=>num*num);
  var addNum = sqNum.reduce((acc,curr)=> acc + curr);
  console.log( addNum )
};

squareSum([1, 2, 2]);
```

This works just fine

Answer (score 0):

```
This is my solution the code wars challenge...Was well

 function square_sum(numbers) {
    return numbers.reduce(function(sum, x) {
      return (x * x) + sum;
    }, 0)
}
```